# Limite de arquivos por pasta - Django 1.7

Tags: python, django, upload, file-upload, sistema-de-arquivos

O Django 1.7 provê algum mecanismo de controle de uploads por pasta? Digo isso porque quando o número de arquivos em uma pasta fica muito grande ela tende a ficar mais lenta.

Um exemplo seria: A cada 800 arquivos em uma pasta, é criada uma pasta na raiz dos uploads com um número sequencial.

Espero que tenha ficado claro.
Obrigado.

Comment: No seu controller faça uma verificação para criar ou não uma nova pasta antes de gravar o arquivo.

Answer (score 1):

Que eu saiba, não há nenhum controle desse tipo, entretanto há uma maneira bem simples de se evitar que as pastas cresçam demais: separando os arquivos pela data de *upload*, através de [`FileField.upload_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to):

```
class MeuModelo(models.Model):
    meu_campo = models.FileField(upload_to='pasta/%Y/%m/%d')
```

A título de exemplo, se você criar uma instância desse modelo em 14/05/2015 com o arquivo `teste.txt` associado ao campo `meu_campo`, e seu `MEDIA_ROOT` for `/var/www/uploads` ele vai ser salvo no arquivo:

```
/var/www/uploads/pasta/2015/05/14/teste.txt
```

Você pode variar a forma de organizar as pastas, usando os mesmos parâmetros do [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/time.html#time.strftime).

Isso não garante, é claro, que as pastas não cresçam além de um tamanho pré-definido (vai que o usuário resolveu cadastrar mais de 800 arquivos no mesmo dia...), nem ajuda em nada caso sua aplicação aceite *upload* de arquivos sem os mesmos estarem associados a modelos. Se isso for um problema pra você, só resta fazer esse controle à mão.